# Sencha Touch Model Associations not populating children

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have an employee-favorites relationship that I have mapped using the hasMany/belongsTo semantics in my models.  In my store, I simply set the root and point to the root array, but I'm not seeing the favorites portion of the model getting populated. Any ideas?

My model for Person:

```
Ext.define('People.model.Employee', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [
        { name: 'cn'}
    ],
    hasMany: { model: 'Favorite', name: 'favorites' }
}});
```

Model for Favorite:

```
Ext.define('People.model.Favorite', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [
        { name: 'uid'},
        { name: 'fullName'}
    ],
    belongsTo: 'Employee'
}});
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('People.store.Favorites', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
requires: [
    'People.model.Employee',
    'People.model.Favorite'
],
config: {
    autoLoad: false,
    model: 'People.model.Employee',
    storeId: 'Favorites',
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: People.app.favSearchUrl,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            idProperty: 'cn',
            rootProperty: 'records'
        }
    }
}});
```

The JSON I'm trying to consume is as follows:

```
    {
    "records": [
        {
            "_id": "5106f97bdcb713b818d7f1f1",
            "cn": "lsacco",
            "favorites": [
                {
                    "fullName": "Friend One",
                    "uid": "friend1"
                },
                {
                    "fullName": "Friend Two",
                    "uid": "friend2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Oh I see the issue, I assumed the hasMany takes are of the attribute, but instead I need to add an explicit field for "Favorites".  Then it populates. :)

Comment: After looking at the examples in the docs, you shouldn't need to put a field in the model for the association.  Any idea why I need to do this?